# how do I change an object after it is called so it can be inserted into a link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, electron

the create link is passed into the linkextension.  I need to change the format of the link that goes into that extension.

```
  function createLink(linkExtension) {

    //const balanceDiv = document.createElement("div");
   // const symbolSpan = document.createElement("span");
    const link = document.createElement("a")
  
    link.setAttribute('href',`https://www.binance.com/en/trade/${linkExtension}_BTC`,);
    link.setAttribute("target","_blank");
  
    
  
    link.textContent = pingObj.symbol;
  
    ticker.appendChild(link);
    pingDiv.appendChild(ticker);
    document.body.appendChild(pingDiv);
  }
```

the pingObj.symbol comes back as coin/btc..    I need to replace the / with _ so that it is displayed coin_btc. The other option is just drop /btc from the result too.  Either way is fine.

```
  createLink(pingObj.symbol)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understood your question. But about the replace issue, why can't you just do `pingObj.symbol.replace("/", "_")` ?

Comment: thanks! I didn't even think of that... my brain is fried today.. That worked perfectly!  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pingObj.symbol.replace("/", "_")`. 
This oneliner will work smoothly.